# How to equip the white winter-wonder-wasteland Pip-Boy?

Tags: fallout-4, ps4

I just obtained the white Pip-Boy and Power Armor paint jobs during the Creation Club free giveaway promotion.  I upgraded some power armor with the new paint, however don't know how to change the Pip-Boy color scheme.

Anyone know how to do this on the PS4?

Answer (score 1):

Found it.  In the Armor Workbench, the Pip-Boy shows up as an inventory item.  Select it, then choose Material and you'll be presented with a list of paint jobs that you've obtained.

Note: some people have found that certain mods prevent the Pip-Boy from appearing in the workbench inventory.  If you don't see it, disable your mods one at a time until you figure out which one causes the problem.

[image: Pip-Boy at Armor Workbench]